# Overriding a method with a generic return type fails after adding a parameter

Tags: java, generics, overriding

I wonder why this is a valid override:

```
public abstract class A {

    public abstract <X> Supplier<X> getSupplier();

    public static class B extends A {

        @Override
        public Supplier<String> getSupplier() {
            return String::new;
        }
    }
}
```

Whereas this is not:

```
public abstract class A {

    public abstract <X> Supplier<X> getSuppliers(Collection<String> strings);

    public static class B extends A {

        @Override
        public Supplier<String> getSuppliers(Collection<String> strings) {
            return String::new;
        }
    }
}
```

According to [JLS §8.4.8.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1), `B.getSupplier` must be a subsignature `A.getSupplier`:

> An instance method mC declared in or inherited by class C, overrides from C another method mA declared in class A, iff all of the following are true:
>
> - ...
> - The signature of mC is a subsignature (§8.4.2) of the signature of mA.
> - ...

Subsignatures are defined in [JLS §8.4.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2):

> Two methods or constructors, M and N, have the *same signature* if they have the same name, the same type parameters (if any) (§8.4.4), and, after adapting the formal parameter types of N to the the type parameters of M, the same formal parameter types.
>
> The signature of a method m1 is a subsignature of the signature of a method m2 if either:

- m2 has the same signature as m1, or
- the signature of m1 is the same as the erasure (§4.6) of the signature of m2.

So it seems like `B.getSupplier` is a subsignature of `A.getSupplier` but `B.getSuppliers` is *not* a subsignature of `A.getSuppliers`.

I wonder how it can be the case.

If `B.getSupplier` is a subsignature of `A.getSupplier` because it has the same erasure, then `B.getSuppliers` must also have the same erasure as `A.getSuppliers`. This should suffice for overriding `getSuppliers` to be legal - but it does not.

If `B.getSupplier` is a subsignature of `A.getSupplier` because it has the same signature, then I wonder what "the same type parameters (if any)" exactly means.

If type parameters are considered, then they should have different type parameters: `A.getSupplier` has type parameter `X`, `B.getSupplier` has none.
If type parameters are not considered then how's `getSuppliers` different?

This is more of an academic question about overrides and generics so please don't suggest refactoring code (like moving type parameter `X` to the class etc.).

I am looking for a formal, JLS-based answer.

From my point of view `B.getSupplier` should not be able override `A.getSupplier` as they don't have the same type parameters. This makes the following code (which produces `ClassCastException`) legal:

```
A b = new B();
URL url = b.<URL>getSupplier().get();
```

Comment: I get a unchecked conversion warning for `A.B.getSupplier()`.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Warning, but not error. So `B.getSupplier` overrides `A.getSupplier`. In case of `getSuppliers` we'll get a compiler error. So `B.getSuppliers` does not override `A.getSuppliers`. Why?

Comment: It also seems to be requirement that the added parameter is a generic type to get the error. e.g. changing it from `Collection<String>` to just `String` makes the error go away.

Comment: Even using a raw type is fine.

Comment: To me it looks like either `<X> Supplier<X> getSupplier()` or `Supplier<String> getSupplier()` must be the _same signature_ as the erasure `Supplier getSupplier()`.

Comment: @Bubletan Why does `public Supplier<String> getSuppliers(Collection<String> strings)` not have the same signature as `public abstract <X> Supplier<String> getSuppliers(Collection<String> strings)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the compiler output, the method signatures are different in both examples (compile the code with `-Xlint:unchecked` option to confirm it):

```
<X>getSupplier() in A (m2)
                                 1st snippet
getSupplier()    in B (m1)


<X>getSuppliers(Collection<String> strings) in A (m2)
                                                           2nd snippet
getSuppliers(Collection<String> strings)    in B (m1)
```

According to the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2) specification, the signature of a method m<sub>1</sub> is a *subsignature* of the signature of a method m<sub>2</sub> if either:

> - m<sub>2</sub> has the same signature as m<sub>1</sub>, **or**
> - the signature of m<sub>1</sub> is the same as the erasure of the signature of m<sub>2</sub>.

The first statement is out of the game - method signatures are different. But what about the second statement and erasure?

### Valid Override

`B.getSupplier()` (m<sub>1</sub>) is a subsignature of `A.<X>getSupplier()` (m<sub>2</sub>), because:

> - the signature of m<sub>1</sub> is the same as the erasure of the signature of m<sub>2</sub>

`<X>getSupplier()` after erasure is equal to `getSupplier()`.

### Invalid Override

`B.getSuppliers(...)` (m<sub>1</sub>) is not a subsignature of `A.<X>getSuppliers(...)` (m<sub>2</sub>), because:

> - the signature of m<sub>1</sub> is not the same as the erasure of the signature of m<sub>2</sub>

The signature of m<sub>1</sub>:

```
getSuppliers(Collection<String> strings);
```

Erasure of the signature of m<sub>2</sub>:

```
getSuppliers(Collection strings);
```

Changing m<sub>1</sub> argument from `Collection<String>` to the raw `Collection` eliminates an error, in this case m<sub>1</sub> becomes a subsignature of m<sub>2</sub>.

### Conclusion

*1st  code snippet (valid override)*: the method signatures in the parent and child classes are different initially. But, after applying the erasure to the parent method the signatures becomes the same.

*2nd code snippet (invalid override)*: the method signatures are different initially and remains different after applying the erasure to the parent method.

Answer (score 1):

The moment you added the parameter it ceased to be an override and became an overload.

Generics have nothing to do with it.

Comment: This does not make sense to me. You basically say that methods with parameters can't override other methods, which is obviously false.

Comment: @lexicore No I didn't. Read what I actually wrote. I said that adding the parameter made it a overload instead of an override. This is by definition, and rather basic.

Comment: Which parameters are changed between `A.getSuppliers` and `B.getSuppliers`?